# Are algorithms on the internet going to 'completely' remove any sort of common ground to discuss and share 'objective' knowledge in the future?

Tags: skepticism, cognitive-bias, social-critique, doubt, internet

I always try to self-analyze whenever I am doing deep research on the internet, and it seems to me that Google usually gives me topics that seem to be in direct views as of my own.

I understand that I might actually be ad-hoc realizing such similarities, but at some point it got to a point where I can predict what I was going to see. I am not sure if Google search engine has algorithm-aided searches and therefore leads to me being trapped in an echo chamber, but this led me to a curious question of the future of ideas over the internet, and if Google tries to maintain such algorithmic way of web searches, specifically searches that show up top. Not a lot of people go to the 3rd or 4th web pages of their searches, and therefore [Google] brings about this likelihood of just refeeding and strengthening of initial ideas and confirmation biases.

So, therefore, I ask: is this a rational fear of mine or am I just exaggerating? Because for some reason this terrifies me incredibly and I really don't know why. How strong is the disparity between different users' algorithms going to get, how big is the distance between thought pockets going to be (especially in the future)? To the point where two people can never have grounds to communicate and understand each other?

Can one truly be skeptic if their source of information feeds them what they want to hear and not what truly is? How does what I mentioned above affect the search for 'objective' knowledge?

Comment: You could use duckduckgo or run your searches through a VPN and solve the problem instead of wondering whether it's a big problem or a little problem.

Comment: @gs you are right but many others probably won't; just saying, google is the most used search engine and if that's the case people being divided by something that's not anything physical but ideologies is pretty scary.

Comment: It's an interesting question but the way it is worded makes it unanswerable. Like nobody but yourself can tell you what scares YOU specifically about that. There are very real problems with that on an objective level, but that would be a different question

Comment: @haxor789 I know what you mean to be honest, I couldn't have worded my question any  better because that is what I am trying to ask. I am trying to understand if this fear is rational not just philosophically but psychologically. Funny story, I really want to understand my psychology for this fear hence why I asked the same question in the psychology stack exchange but both times my question got closed and I was redirected here.

Comment: @Howwhye Well you could rephrase it in the sense of how to deal with "yeah"-sayers. So receiving only affirming feedback. And that is one of the rare occasions where there should be plenty of material given that it touches on the problems of the powerful who had the power to write down those questions.. Most likely the answer that you should get is "touch some grass" so go outside make real world observations by yourself rather than relying on other people's observations.

Comment: @Howwhye The other thing that might be scary is about the nature of the relation between you and the internet. So who is the agent and who is the tool and what if any are their objectives? Like Is google a tool? Is it just a search engine that helps you find something and are you shaping the tool according to your will so that it improves your searches. Or is google an entity of it's own that tries to shape you according to it's will and so are you "learning" how to use it or are you taught. Likely both, you learn how to get good results while google tries to learn how to serve you ads..

Comment: A [social media detox](https://www.calm.com/blog/social-media-detox) can be very helpful [For all of us]. And yeah stackexchange is very much a gamed social media

Comment: @Rushi Yes, I agree very much. I am trying my best to do so.

Comment: @haxor789 With the advent of social media and the fact that we can't be everywhere at the same time, we have to depend on things told by others. This is the nature of our society and thus with the growth of social media, internet and technology this dependency is going to grow, I can say for sure because I see myself being dependent on it even more hence my fear. Now I think I understand where my fear stems from, possibly the future and the direction we are headed to which I feel is rational. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

That's a great question, and the problem is real. However -- and I don't know it supposed to make anyone feel better -- this problem is also a very very old one. Basically, it goes to the heart of human nature.

When it comes to human behaviour, every individual has at their disposal two distinct mental faculties that help them decide on their next move. One of them aims to *understand* the person's circumstances -- and if successful, it allows them to "think for themselves". Unfortunately, piecing together one's understanding is not an easy task. On top of that, society does not teach this skill -- this art -- systematically, it does not even tell us that this is how we are supposed to use our brains. Instead, it appears that society leaves it to chance -- and the capacity for critical thinking varies greatly between individuals.

Fortunately, a person can always rely the other mental faculty -- it can't understand, but it can learn ideas and habits by observing other people's behaviour. We look for role models -- first our parents, then the cool kids, influencers, gurus, leaders -- anyone we deem worthy of imitation (and that's why imitation is the sincerest form of flattery). We try to imitate their understanding -- except how can we tell that they themselves are not imitating it?

Maybe you see what I am getting at.

We imitate each other, creating these potentially dangerous feedbacks loops. Even bad ideas become more acceptable as they gains popularity -- increasing their acceptance and popularity still.

> I am surrounded by people
> who love to argue and fight.
> The law has become paralyzed ...
> The wicked far outnumber the righteous,
> so that justice has become perverted. (Habakkuk 1:2-4)

This is how millions seemingly reasonable and even likeable people ended up voting for Hitler, and then went to [courageously die for him](https://youtu.be/1SdO-btKuds?si=pJwL08Dvt-N5I711).

In other words, this imitation game is in our very nature. It can lead to runaway conditions, it can tear societies apart, and it did. The real question, therefore, is not whether this could happen, but why this is not happening more often? What holds our societies together?

Comment: Do you see our societies holding together??? Not anywhere I can find... Maybe some remote Pacific islands... And even those face submergence as global warming raises the oceans

Answer (score 2):

I can make an argument that your feared phenomenon was worse before the advent of the internet and search engines. When I was growing up- in the 1960s- the main sources of information were school text books, TV and radio, newspapers and library books. Do you think those sources were unbiased? On the contrary, they reinforced perniciously stereotypical thinking on all kinds of subjects, and fed the population with a narrow selection of information. Today, by contrast, we have access to more information than we can possibly consume. Even if Google did not have some bias in its algorithms, how would you know which sources, in the giant haystack of information, were the most objective and trustworthy? Ultimately it is up to you to be rigorously discerning in your approach to discovering and assessing information. If you want to avoid swallowing someone else's worldview, don't allow yourself to be spoon-fed.

Comment: I think you are absolutely correct, I am responsible for my views and so to discern the information I consume, but I think about the masses; everyone else who don't feel the need to do the work to justify the information they get but instead accept it at face value from the source they get it from. This by itself scares me a lot (especially in the future), after all we live in a society.

Comment: I think you're missing the point here. The problem isn't so much that the sources are biased and untrustworthy, the problem is that previously propaganda was mass produced so everyone got the same version, which obviously lacked in accuracy especially around the edges. But nowadays a customized reality is created just for you... Like if I gave you book X and told you it's life altering, you could read the same book but the effect upon you could be very different. But if I told you to google "X", what you see might be radically different from what I see.